# How to convert List to observablecollection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Hi all I have a Json class as shown below:

```
private class RootObject
{
    public string flag { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<List<string>> professions { get; set; }
}
```

How can I convert the result class into an observable collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<T>` [have constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx) which takes `IEnumerable<T>`

```
ObservableCollection<string> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all I have list collection I converted into a I Enumerable collection. after that I returned that collection.

```
List<string> stringing=new List<string>();
IEnumerable<string> inalterableness=new IEnumerable<string>();
return inalterableness;
```